# How to do this calculation in R?

Tags: r, calculation

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
groups <- c(1:20)
values1 <- c(1,3,2,4,2,5,1,6,2,7,3,5,2,6,3,5,1,5,3,4)
values2 <- c(3,2,4,1,5,2,4,1,3,2,6,1,4,2,5,3,7,1,4,2)
sample.data <- data.frame(groups,values1,values2)
head(sample.data)

  groups values1 values2
1      1       1       3
2      2       3       2
3      3       2       4
4      4       4       1
5      5       2       5
6      6       5       2
```

Description: a dataframe that has 20 sets of values (values1 and values2) of 20 different groups. The numbers follow these patterns: 
(1) The numbers are alternatively highs and lows
(2) If a number in the `values1` column is higher than its 2 adjacent numbers, the corresponding number in  `values2` column will be lower than its 2 adjacent numbers (as can be seen in the sample)

What I want to calculate from these numbers is called the "delta value" (dV) - which is calculated as the differences between a high-value number and the mean of the 2 low-value numbers adjacent to it. For example, for the first 3-number set of the `values1` column (1,3,2), the first dV would be 3-((2+1)/2)=1.5; then take the last number of that set as the first number of the next set, do the same calculation, so the second dV is 4-((2+2)/2)=2; and so on. Then record all of these dV values for the `values1` column in a new column called `dV1`. Do the same thing for the `values2` column and record all the dV values in a new `dV2` column. Note that in the `values2` column, the first number is higher than the second one, so ignore it and start the calculation with the next 3-number set (2,4,1) and repeat the calculation as above.

So how do I execute this calculation in R?

Thank you in advance!

P/S: Sorry, this is a long question but I think it's got all the required information for the calculation.

Comment: What do you want the dV1 column to have in the odd rows?

Comment: It would be helpful to give the desired output for the sample input so possible solutions can be verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to use the `dV` values for plotting, it might be easiest to do this twice, once for each column

```
library(dplyr)
sample.data1 <- sample.data %>% 
  mutate(alt = row_number()%%2,
         mean_adj_1 = (lag(values1) + lead(values1))/2,
         dV1 = (values1 - mean_adj_1) * (1-alt)) %>% 
  filter(alt == 0 & !is.na(dV1)) %>% 
  select(-c(alt:mean_adj_1))

sample.data.2 <- sample.data %>% 
  mutate(alt = row_number()%%2,
         mean_adj_2 = (lag(values2) + lead(values2))/2,
         dV2 = (values2 - mean_adj_2) * alt) %>% 
  filter(alt == 1 & !is.na(dV2)) %>% 
  select(-c(alt:mean_adj_2))
```

Explanation: this could probably be done in fewer steps but this way you can see what's going on. The `mean_adj` columns get you the mean of the row before and after, and the `alt` column is what lets you put zeroes in the rows you don't want `dV` calculated for. The the `dV` column is simply `value - mean_adj`.

Result:

```
 > sample.data.1
  groups values1 values2 dV1
1      2       3       2 1.5
2      4       4       1 2.0
3      6       5       2 3.5
4      8       6       1 4.5
5     10       7       2 4.5
6     12       5       1 2.5
7     14       6       2 3.5
8     16       5       3 3.0
9     18       5       1 3.0
> sample.data.2
  groups values1 values2 dV2
1      3       2       4 2.5
2      5       2       5 3.5
3      7       1       4 2.5
4      9       2       3 1.5
5     11       3       6 4.5
6     13       2       4 2.5
7     15       3       5 2.5
8     17       1       7 5.0
9     19       3       4 2.5
```

Comment: and if I want to plot or use just the rows with numbers in the dV1 and dV2 columns (those without zeros), how do I extract them? (sorry if this is a silly question, I'm fairly new to R). Thanks

Comment: Do you just need the two dV columns, without the zeroes? That is, `dV1 = c(1.5, 2, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 3, 3)` and likewise for `dV2`?

Comment: Yeah, almost. Sorry for being a pain, but what if I want to apply this code to a larger dataset (say 8000 data rows), is there any code that can select the non-zeros in order and pass them on (maybe a vector, an object, or likewise so that I can do sorts of plots and other analyses)?

Comment: I'm sure there is, I just need to know if you need to keep any of the information in the other columns along with the `dV` results.

Comment: Yes, I need the original columns intact, since I'm going to present them along with the dV values

Comment: But if it's not possible, then maybe the dV columns can be extracted and treated separately from the others? Essentially I just need the original data, and the dV values.

Comment: @TungLinh Updated the answer.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I thought it deleted the original at first but then realised it's just the newly created sets with the dV values in. Thank you very much for your quick response :D